# Swallowing hurts after BJJ neck restraint

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, injury

Swallowing hurts (like when I have a bad cold) since someone did a neck restraint to me during BJJ sparring 8 days ago.

[image]

As the symptom is still there I'm wondering if I don't have something "broken" in the throat, or something. Is that possible?

Comment: Yup, happening to me right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you strained a muscle or bruised your esophagus.

This has happened to me 3 times. The first time I went to the doctor and she prescribed me prescription strength ibuprofen and said to come back if the pain did not go away in two weeks. The second time I simply took Advil (over the counter ibuprofen) and the pain went away in a few weeks. The 3rd time the pain lasted for almost 2 months but it did go away. I should note in all three instances I did not return to BJJ until my neck was completely healed.

Comment: Sounds like that's what happened to me then, did you get to know exactly what caused the pain in the 3 instances?

Comment: First time was from a rear-naked choke, but the guy kind of swung his arm at my neck like a karate chop. The second & third time were from collar chokes. The biggest take away from these experiences is best explained from a Wu-tang clan quote "Ya best protect your neck!". Also I think warm tea with honey helps, but I'm totally not qualified to give medical advice. The pain always went away before I considered going to a eye, ear, and throat specialist to get an exact diagnosis.

Comment: Cool thanks for the extra info! One more thing: did you consider making your neck stronger with neck exercises (with or without weights added) as a protection?

Comment: @drake035 Yeah after the pain went away I started doing a lot of yes-no's, and shoulder shrugs (not sure if that's actually the name of the exercise). I don't know of any exercises that involve weights (just increased the reps).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have any existing medical problems in your neck, then, with the massive disclaimer that I am no medical expert, I wonder if you have simply bruised your neck. It can happen.

That said, I would urge you to get it checked. It's inevitable that you'll get sprains and bruises from martial arts training, but the neck is kind of important, being as it houses your airways and the blood supply to your brain. I wouldn't ignore any neck injury. I think it's unlikely after 8 days, but you can't rule out the slim but dangerous possibly of the injury swelling, and closing up your airways.